# What exactly is Jubilee Year and Jubilee Day in England (a snippet from an old story)

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, archaic-language

I am reading a short story by R. Middleton and I failed to find out what the Jubilee phrases refer to (the story takes place in 1897, and was written around this year as well):

> Ninety-seven was **Jubilee year**, **the year of the second Jubilee**, you
> remember, and we had great doings at Fairfield, so that we hadn't much
> time to bother about the ghost-ship though anyhow it isn't our way to
> meddle in things that don't concern us. (...) **On Jubilee Day**, however,
> somebody told Captain Roberts why the church bells were ringing, and
> he hoisted a flag and fired off his guns like a loyal Englishman.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Queen Victoria succeeded to the throne in 1837, so her Golden Jubilee (50 years) was celebrated in 1887 and her Diamond Jubilee in 1897. There do not appear to have been any particular celebrations for her Silver Jubilee (25 years), as there were for the present Queen in 1977, so the 1897 one was thought of as 'the second jubilee'.

https://www.royal.uk/history-jubilees